# Frequency and next words for a word of a bigram list in python

Tags: python

I have this sentence: `'Johnny Johnny yes papa'`, and I want to calculate the frequency of next word for each word. In this case I turn the sentence into circular:

```
sentence = 'Johnny Johnny yes papa'
sentence = sentence.split()
sentence.append(sentence[0])
```

Now the sentence is `['Johnny','Johnny','yes','papa','Johnny']`

I create the bigrams in this way:

```
def to_bigrams(my_list):
  bigrams = [(my_list[i],my_list[i+1]) for i,element in enumerate(my_list) if i<len(my_list)-1]
  return bigrams

my_bigrams = to_bigrams(sentence)
```

And now my bigrams are: `[('Johnny', 'Johnny'), ('Johnny', 'yes'), ('yes', 'papa'), ('papa', 'Johnny')]`

Now for example `Johnny` has two outcomes: `Johnny` and `yes`, and `yes` has only one outcome which is `papa` and `papa` has only one outcome which is `Johnny` so the expected dictionary is:

```
{'Johnny':['Johnny','yes'],'yes':['papa'],'papa':['Johnny']}
```

I have tried this:

```
my_freq_dict = {my_bigrams[i][0]:my_bigrams[i][j] for i,element in enumerate(my_bigrams) for j in range(len(my_bigrams))}
```

But I get this error: `IndexError: tuple index out of range`. There is something wrong with my logic, please, could you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way using `dict.setdefault`:

```
my_bigrams = [('Johnny', 'Johnny'), ('Johnny', 'yes'), ('yes', 'papa'), ('papa', 'Johnny')]

d = {}
for v1, v2 in my_bigrams:
    d.setdefault(v1, []).append(v2)
d
```

Output:

```
{'Johnny': ['Johnny', 'yes'], 'yes': ['papa'], 'papa': ['Johnny']}
```

Your try is creating error because you are using `len(my_bigrams)` instead of `len(element)`.

Fixing it, however, won't yield the expected output since some keys appear more than once and thus will be overwritten by the latest entry (which is what `dict` is meant to do).

Comment: I got the idea, if there is no value, your default is an empty list and then you append the second term of the tuples! Thank you very much @Chris, I appreciate your time for explaining my error and giving an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)

```
from itertools import groupby

res = {key: [x[1] for x in group]for key, group in groupby(sorted(data, key=lambda x: x[0]), key= lambda x: x[0])}
print(res)
```

**Output:**

```
{'Johnny': ['Johnny', 'yes'], 'yes': ['papa'], 'papa': ['Johnny']}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer @deadshot, an interesting use of a comprehension dictionary